# Permission denied, need to install brushes gimp

Tags: permissions, gimp

While adding brushes to GIMP I got this message:

```
Could not open '/home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr' for reading:
Error opening file /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr: Permission denied
```

I have ownership over those directories so I don't know why GIMP can't access them.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Based on the pathnames, I'm assuming you installed GIMP as a snap? if so, please [edit] your question to include the output of `snap connections gimp`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce that issue, but for me downloading a Brush Archive and extracting it to the desired location worked just fine.

Hence I think that answering the question requires some additional information. I do not have enough reputation to comment yet, hence I write this as an answer even though I primarily ask for additional information.

- Which method of adding brushes do you use for GIMP (provided you use a method which is different from what I did above)
- are you absolutely sure that you own the files and that the path exists?

You could try

```bsh
sudo chown -R $(whoami):users ~/snap/gimp/
chmod -R u+r ~/snap/gimp
```

in order to make sure that the directory is owned by you and you possess the rights to read contained files, but I think that is a bad idea. I would not override the default permissions for the entire directory recursively as done by the aforementioned command, but to check the permissions and rights added to the specific files:

```bsh
ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr
```

This should be something like

```
-rw-r--r--  1 [YOUR USER NAME] users
```

esp. have read rights granted to user, group and others.

Therefore I would appreciate if you could provide the output of

```bsh
ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr
```

and maybe also information on the user which launched gimp via

```
ps aux | grep gimp
```

I hope I do not offend you in any way by asking you to recheck the permissions, it is hard to guess the level of experience and as this seems to be a straight-forward permission problem I think it is best to double-check.

Comment: @steeldriver I did <sudo nautilus> but all the GIMP and Inkscape files are locked and can not change permission. I  finally had to make a folder in home directory named brushes and shared the fonts system-wide. Installed via Flatpak.

Comment: Though I would not recommend launching GUI applications as root, this indicates that there are some issues with permissions or ownership. Could you provide the output of
`ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr` and `ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/` if the former command fails due to missing 'execute' permissions for the directories for your user?

Comment: // mycrap@MYCRAP:~$ ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1079094 Nov 18 07:36 /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr
mycrap@MYCRAP:~$ ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 mycrap mycrap 4096 Jan 23 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 mycrap mycrap 4096 Jan 23 16:24 ..
dr-xr-xr-x 4 mycrap mycrap 4096 Jan 23 15:11 227
drwxr-xr-x 3 mycrap mycrap 4096 Jan 23 15:11 common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mycrap mycrap    3 Jan 23 15:11 current -> 227
mycrap@MYCRAP:~$

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):mycrap /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config` 
should fix your issue, even though the permissions seem somewhat unusual.

Comment: I need access to these files to add fonts, extensions, and other addons. First time I have had this issue, been using thee programs for 10 years on Windows, just migrated to Linux most recently.

Comment: What I ment with 'permissions look unusual': the .abr file has read, write, and execute rights for user, group and other. Especially the execute rights are not needed from what I understand. 

Did 
`sudo chown -R $(whoami):mycrap /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config`
fix your issue? In theory, you should be able to access these files when launching your file browser (nautilus, but not as root) and also in GIMP.  If it does not work, the output of the aforementioned command and 
`ls -la /home/mycrap/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/brushes/bolts1_HMS.abr`
re-executed would be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103665/discussion-between-mutablevoid-and-corey-fairbanks).